# keyboard input to save image detected from video stream in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I was trying to do facial recognition using opencv and save the image detected in the cvRect when an input from the keyboard(in my case, when "c" on the keyboard is pressed, an image should be created with the detected face in the folder. ) However, I guess the interrupt (`cvWaitKey()`) is giving me lots of problems and there is no response from the system. Would really appreciate your input in this area!

The code is here:

```
char d = cvWaitKey(33);

if (d==67) // if the keyboard c is pressed
{   
    // r is the cvRect created for the face detected
    cvSetImageROI(img, cvRect(pt1.x,pt1.y,r->width,r->height));

    //img is the video frame passed in here
    IplImage* img2 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),img->depth,img->nChannels);

    cvCopy(img, img2, NULL);

    cvResetImageROI(img);

    cvSaveImage("roi.jpg",img2);
}
```

The code before this will be very standard face detection from webcam. And it works. thanks!

Comment: Can you tell what the problem is exactly? Is it not entering the block or something else?

Answer (score 2):

67? It's clearer to write `'C'`. That would also have shown you the real problem: you probably meant `'c'`